# First order theory - define a domain with an even number of elements

Tags: order-theory, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I'm trying to write a first-order theory that defines a domain of even size (containing an even number of elements). I'm told that I can use a single binary predicate symbol, R, that can be defined as I see fit. I can also assume that infinite sets are "even size".

What I've come up with is the following:

$$∀x\ ∀y\ ∃z\ (R(x,y) ↔ R(z,y))$$

where R(x,y) means x is less than y.

However, after looking at this more closely, it seems that all I'm saying is that each element has an immediate successor. How can I modify this to explicitly say that for every element, there is exactly one element following it? I'm struggling to see how I can state that the pattern continues on the element *after* that, rather than linking all elements in one chain.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your axiom is a tautology: simply pick $z=x$.

Comment: Don't think in terms of successor. Think in in terms of: every element is paired with exactly one other element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: Write a sentence that says that $R$ satisfies the following condition: $R$ is symmetric, and for each $x$ there is a unique $y\ne x$ such that $R(x,y)$. (And of course explain why this does what you want.)

Comment: Okay so would it make sense for the theory to consist of two formulas? The first of which proclaims it as symmetric: ∀x∀y R(x,y) → R(y,x). And the second being: ∀x∃y R(x,y). And then I simply define in English that R(x,y) denotes a relationship in which each x has a unique y? Or would that description also have to be a part of the theory, itself?

Comment: @user2901181: Not quite. You want your second sentence to say that $y$ is different from $x$: $\forall x\,\exists y\,(x\ne y\land R(x,y))$. But even that’s not enough: you have to add a further conjunct inside the main parenthesis that says that this $y$ is unique. Do you see how to do that?

Comment: This is what I'm thinking now: $∀x∃y(x≠y∧R(x,y)∧∀z(R(x,y)→¬y=z)$. So in addition to the previous one, a relationship between $x$ and $y$ implies that for all $z$, $y$ does not equal $z$. This doesn't seem right to me though because this wouldn't hold if $z=x$...

Comment: @user2901181: That can’t work, because it’s always false: $\forall z$ includes the case $z=y$. How about $\forall z(R(x,z)\to \ldots)$? Can you fill in the blank?

Comment: $∀x∃y(x≠y∧R(x,y)∧∀z(R(x,z)→z=y)$ ? So for all z, if we know a relationship between x and y exists, then this must imply that a relationship between that same x and z indicates that z must be y. This is because x cannot possibly have more than one element paired with it?

Comment: @user2901181: Looks good.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again! (I'm pretty sure you helped me out with a similar first order theory question yesterday.) The step by step guidance is far more helpful than just replying with an answer. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @user2901181: You’re very welcome! Yes, I prefer to try to nudge people towards a solution; I think that you learn more that way.